# Show that $ \Phi(x,z) = x^{\delta} \cdot \prod_{p \le z} \bigg(1-\frac{1}{p^{\delta}}\bigg)^{-1}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I am stuck at the following exercise:

> Let $\Phi(x, z)$ be the number of $n \le x$ all of whose prime factors are less than or equal to $z$. Prove that for any $\delta > 0$ holds
>
> $$ \Phi(x,z) \le x^{\delta} \cdot \prod_{p \le z} \bigg(1-\frac{1}{p^{\delta}}\bigg)^{-1}.$$

I recognise the similarity of $\prod_{p \le z} \bigg(1-\frac{1}{p^{\delta}}\bigg)^{-1}$ to the Euler Product and if I am not mistaken it should thus hold:

$$\prod_{p \le z} \bigg(1-\frac{1}{p^{\delta}}\bigg)^{-1} = \prod_{p \le z} \frac{1}{1-p^{-\delta}}$$

But I do not see how this could help me.

Comment: Hint: Use inclusion-exclusion principle.
Question: There should be any $\delta$ in the term $\Phi(x,z)$?

Comment: @Savio: Sorry, I made a typo, there was meant to be an $\le$ instead of an equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\prod_{p \le z} \bigg(1-\frac{1}{p^{\delta}}\bigg)^{-1}=\sum_{n\ge 1,LargestPrimeFactor(n)\le z} n^{-\delta}$$
If $n\le x$ then $x^\delta n^{-\delta}$..